# Need to update a MySQL table with Millions of rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two table shere:

```
Cities
Region| City Name 

States
ID| State | Region_Key
```

I need to do an update query on the cities table like so i.e set cities.region = statres.id where states.region_key = cities.region

The problem is that the cities database has over 2.7 million records and I tried doing a query like this only for mysql to hang and die out.

```
update cities c, states c set c.region = s.id where c.region = s.region_key
```

EDIT ===================

This is the sql I am using but its not working I get an error saying incorrect usage of UPDATE and LIMIT

```
update cities w, states s 
set w.region_id = s.id, 
w.updated = 1 
where w.region = s.w_code and w.updated = 0
LIMIT 10000
```

Comment: break up into batches, perhaps using another column (such as a datetime), or if non-suitable introduce a row_number()

Comment: You're using the alias "c" twice, for each table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Add a nullable bit column [HasBeenUpdated] to the `cities` table
2. Add `Set c.HasBeenUpdated = 1` to the update clause
3. Add the following where condition `AND c.HasBeenUpdated IS NULL`
4. Add a new `WHERE` condition `AND c.ID in (Select ID from Cities where HasBeenUpdated Is Null Limit 10000)`. This is needed because you cannot use a `Limit` statement on a multi-table `Update` ([source](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html)). This also presumes that you have an ID column as the PK for cities (if not, then consider adding one). Now the update statement will only process 10,000 rows at a time (and will only process unprocessed rows).

If you can put this in a loop using your application logic, then this can be used for automation. Change the limit number based on your needs and when it is done, remove the `HasBeenUpdated` column.

This should allow you to minimize the impact of the update on the table and database, and allow you to perform it across the whole table in manageable batches.

**Edit**: Update step 4 to filter rows to be updated via subquery, since a Limit statement cannot be used on a multi-table Update.

Comment: you mean 'WHERE c.hasBeenUpdated IS NULL', surely?

Comment: Not working :( I get an erorr saying Wrong usage of UPDATE and LIMIT, I'm using two tables here

Comment: Adding a nullable bit column to a 2.7 million row table can be as long as updating the table directly.

Comment: @sanmai - maybe. But I put my first answer up 5 hours ago, and less than an hour later, the OP had already added the column and was running into errors with the update query. So anecdotal evidence seems to be that maybe adding the column can be done relatively quickly.

Answer (score 1):

Use `SELECT INTO NEW_TABLE` to create a new table  with desired content, and then drop/rename older table and use `RENAME TABLE` to rename newely created table into proper name:

```
CREATE TABLE new_cities SELECT 
   states.id AS region_id, cities.name 
FROM cities JOIN states ON cities.region = states.w_code;

RENAME TABLE cities TO old_cities, new_cities TO cities;
```